# $|u+w| = |u| + |w|$ iff $\langle u,w \rangle =0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products

I was asked what needs to hold such that $|u+w|=|u|+|w|$. Where $u,w \in \mathbb R^n$.

Well, first notice that if $|u+w|=|u|+|w|$ then $|u+w|^2 = |u|^2 + 2|u||w|+|w|^2$

if we go by the definition $|v|=\sqrt{\langle v,v \rangle}$ which I think is the most standard definition (where $\langle .\rangle$ is some inner product), then we have:

$|u+w|^2 = \langle u+w , u+w \rangle=\langle u ,u \rangle+\langle u , w \rangle +\langle w , u \rangle+\langle w,w \rangle=|u|^2+2\langle u,w \rangle +|w|^2$

And so for $|u+w|^2 = |u|^2 + 2|u||w|+|w|^2$ to hold, we must have $2\langle u,w \rangle = 2|u||w|$ or in other words,

$\langle u,w \rangle = \sqrt{ \langle u,u \rangle \langle w,w \rangle }$

Why is this true iff  $\langle u,w \rangle = 0$? Doesn't seem correct, and that was the answer the teacher gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the question that the teach *meant* to ask was find a condition such that
$$
|u+v|^2 = |u|^2 + |v|^2
$$
Note that the desired if and only if statement holds only for *real* vector spaces.

Comment: I see. So the condition that the inner product will be zero is false in my case? What is the condition for my case? I can see that if $u=kw$ where $k \in \mathbb R$ then indeed the equality holds, but I'm not sure that if the equality holds then $u=kw$. And yes I know, it's only for real vectors, since for complex vectors we need the conjugate, it isnt symmetric.

Comment: Yes, if the equality holds, then $u = kw$ with $k \geq 0$. Even with the conjugate, the corresponding result fails for complex spaces.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. How would you prove it? I mean, suppose $\langle u , w \rangle = \sqrt { \langle u ,u \rangle \langle w , w \rangle}$, why does that mean $w=ku$? I suppose multiplying sums is inevitable.

Comment: Any proof of the Cauchy Schwarz inequality will include a proof of a statement to this effect. Try your textbook.

Comment: The quick explanation is simply to say that $u$ can be broken into $u = u_1 + u_2$ with $u_1$ parallel to $w_1$ and $u_2$ perpendicular.  We then note that $|\langle u,w \rangle| = \|u_1\|\|w\|$, and that $\|u\|^2 = \|u_1\|^2 + \|u_2\|^2$.